# How to Submit Polymorphic Comments on Feed? [Error]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, feed

If a user clicks the **[+ Comment]** button

[image]

he is confronted with this evil beast:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CommentsController#create
Couldn't find Comment with 'id'=
Line: @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
```

**activities/index**

```
<%= link_to activity.user.name, activity.user %>
<%= render "activities/#{activity.trackable_type.underscore}/#{activity.action}", activity: activity %>
<%= render "comments/comments", comments: activity.comments %>
<%= render "comments/form", new_comment: Comment.new(commentable_id: activity.id, commentable_type: activity.class.model_name) %>
```

**comments/_form**

```
<%= form_for new_comment do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :content, rows: 4, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Comment' %>
  <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn") do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Comment
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**activities_controller**

```
def index
  @activities = Activity.order("created_at desc").where(user_id: current_user.following_ids)
  @commentable = @activity
  @comment = Comment.new
end
```

The error can be found here:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_commentable
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :like]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

    def index
        @comments = @commentable.comments
    end

    def new
        @comment = @commentable.comments.new
    end

    def create
        @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
        if @comment.save
            redirect_to @commentable, notice: "comment created."
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    def edit
        @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
        if @comment.update_attributes(comment_params)
            redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Comment was updated."
        else
            render :edit
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
        @comment.destroy
        redirect_to @commentable, notice: "comment destroyed."
    end

  def like
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment_like = current_user.comment_likes.build(comment: @comment)
    if @comment_like.save
            @comment.increment!(:likes)
        flash[:success] = 'Thanks for liking!'
    else
        flash[:error] = 'Two many likes'
      end  
        redirect_to(:back)
  end

private
  def set_comment
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end

    def load_commentable
        resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2]
        @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id) #Here it is!
    end

    def comment_params
        params[:comment][:user_id] = current_user.id
        params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :commentable, :user_id, :like)
    end
end
```

The error came about from the answer here: [How to Add Polymorphic Comments to Feed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29778140/how-to-add-polymorphic-comments-to-feed/29778414#29778414)

**development.log**

```html
Started POST "/comments" for ::1 at 2015-04-23 20:12:14 -0400
Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"hU1lxg2BMqSyBo8j2SGiEB4wZ3ez5kz/E64mp6ssbwBnh+DddyTtNQxY+IYCluHHvs2wIBxrtD5hQVA5sGtXBg==", "comment"=>{"content"=>"test"}, "button"=>""}
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  [1m[36mHabit Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "habits".* FROM "habits" WHERE "habits"."user_id" = ?[0m  [["user_id", 2]]
  [1m[35mHabit Load (2.5ms)[0m  SELECT "habits".* FROM "habits"
  [1m[36mActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE (LOWER(name) = LOWER('ingrain'))[0m
  [1m[35mComment Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 16ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Comment with 'id'=):
  app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:61:in `load_commentable'
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: May I ask what you are trying to do with that line?  It looks like it is working out to `Comment.find(id)`.  If so, can you simplify?  Separately, the core issue is that `@commentable` can be nil and you are not protecting against that from what I can see.

Comment: Hey @steveklein yea I think we can simplify to that which would give us: `undefined local variable or method 'id`. I got the code form this railscasts episode: http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised. He also offers another alternative: `def load_commentable
   klass = [Valuation].detect { |c| params["#{c.name.underscore}_id"]}
   @commentable = klass.find(params["#{klass.name.underscore}_id"])
 end` which then gives `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass` for the 2nd line.

Comment: We need to determine the name of the commentable resource and its id. We’ll get these from request.path by splitting it at every slash and grabbing the second and third elements so if the path is /valuations/1 these will be the two elements used. We can use these to set `@commentable` by calling singlularize.classify.constantize to get the class of the model and calling find on that to get the instance by the id. Not sure how to work around it @steveklein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, for this to work, it looks like it is setup for comments to be a **nested resource** of whatever you're commenting on in your routes file.

So, if you want comments on activities, you'd have:

```
resources :activites do
  resources :comments
end
```

This way, when the #load_commentable method picks apart the request path, it'll get the commentable and id from the first two segments.

It looks, instead, like you're trying to use comments as a top level resource.

**UPDATE:**
When you call your partial, simply pass along the url helper that the form should use. Like this:

```
<%= render "comments/form", new_comment: Comment.new(commentable_id: activity.id, commentable_type: activity.class.model_name), create_url: :activity_comments_path %>
```

Then, over in the partial, simply invoke that helper and pass the result as the url option - like this:

```
<%= form_for new_comment, url: send(create_url, new_comment.commentable)
```

Comment: I already had that but I also had it as a top level resource. I removed it as a top level resource and now I get an error message: `undefined method 'comments_path' for ...` line: `<%= form_for new_comment do |f| %>` so maybe you're onto something.

Comment: When you pass the new_comment local variable to the partial, try it as activity.comments.build - if that doesn't generate the path using the nested resource's path helper, then you can simply pass along the path helper you wanna use as well.

Comment: Hey Joe Martinez just finished chat with Steve. We couldn't solve it. Might not be possible. Are you willing to chat? Thanks Joe!

Comment: It's definitely possible - you just have to pass through the path helper to your comments partial. Does stack exchange have a chat function?

Comment: Yea maybe you can help me give this a try before I completely give up. Meet me over here if you can Joe: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76301/room-for-anthonygalli-com-and-joe-martinez Thanks for the help!

Comment: Joe what time works for you? Did you change your mind about chatting? Sorry about the persistence I just really want to get this done - your my last hope :/

Comment: Looks like we're never online at the same time - lol. If you post your view and your partial in a gist, I'll show you the change that I think will fix it.

Comment: I updated my example with how you would pass along the url helper to make this work. Make sure you use the nested routes I described in the first part of my answer as well. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In the `load_commentable` before action, you could redirect to an error page or something if `@commentable` is `nil`.  As it is, you are trying to access attributes of this `nil` object in other methods (`create` in the case of this error).

Comment: I'm having a hard time implementing what you mean :/ The problem lies when I hit submit so wouldn't they all be nil since it needs to save first? Are you suggesting I add a conditional to the line `before_action :load_commentable`? Never seen that so I think I'm misunderstanding. sorry Steve.

Comment: Don't you expect `@commentable` to be valid (not `nil`) when you `create` a `comment`?  You are just using the `before_action` as a convenience - if you were to move that code at the start of each dependent action, you would never operate on a potentially `nil` object.  That is why I am not a fan of using `before_action` in this way - it is not very transparent.  At the end of `load_commentable` you can add `redirect_to root_path if @commentable == nil`.  We can set up a chat if needed.

Comment: Let's do it! I ran into a problem with your most recent comment. Want to meet me here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76194/room-for-anthonygalli-com-and-steve-klein?