# How to make a path to a paginated url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, pagination, will-paginate

When user #1 likes/comments on user #2, user #2 gets a notification:

**notifications/_notifications.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "", notification_path(notification.id), method: :delete, class: "glyphicon glyphicon-remove" %> <%= link_to Comment.find_by(notification.comment_id).user.name, user_path(Comment.find_by(notification.comment_id).user.id) %> commented on <%= link_to "your activity", (notification.activity_id) %>
```

but upon user #2 clicking the notification it doesn't lead anywhere since I removed the `activity_path`, if I put it back before `(notification.activity_id)` we get an error:

> No route matches 
>   {:action=>"show", :controller=>"activities", > :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

I don't know if this is possible, but upon clicking on the notification **user #2 would be taken to the paginated page where the activity i**s. There are 20 activities per page via the `gem will_paginate` so if the activity that was commented on is on page 2 then upon clicking on the activity, user #2 should be directed to: http://0.0.0.0:3000/activities?page=2

This would at least narrow down where the comment is on the activity feed for the user.

**activities/index.html.erb**

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
    <%= link_to activity.user.name, activity.user %>
    <%= render "activities/#{activity.trackable_type.underscore}/#{activity.action}", activity: activity %>

      <% activity.activity_likers.each do |user| %>
          <%= user.name %>
      <% end %>

    <%= link_to like_activity_path(:id => activity.id), class: "btn", method: :post do %>
      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up'></span> Like
    <% end %>

    <%= render "comments/comments", comments: activity.comments %>
    <%= render "comments/form", new_comment: Comment.new(commentable_id: activity.id, commentable_type: activity.class.model_name), create_url: :activity_comments_path %>

<% end %>

<%= will_paginate @activities %>
```

**activities_controller.rb**

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @activities = Activity.order("created_at desc").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
    end

    def show
          redirect_to(:back)
    end
end
```

Please let me know if you need anymore code if you find that this is possible to do :)

## UPDATE

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
    def index
    @notifications = current_user.notifications
    @notifications.each do |notification|
        notification.update_attribute(:read, true)
        activity = Activity.find(notification.activity_id) #Gives "Couldn't find Activity with 'id'=". I then removed ".activity_id" to see what happens next.
            index    = Activity.order(created_at: :desc).index(activity)
            page_number = (index / per_page.to_f).ceil #I am then told "undefined local variable or method `per_page'" so I tried making it :per_page to which I then get: "undefined method `to_f' for :per_page:Symbol"
    end
    end


    def destroy
      @notification = Notification.find(params[:id])
      @notification.destroy
      redirect_to :back
    end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :activities do
  resources :comments
  resources :notifications
  member do
    post :like
    post :notifications
  end
end
```

### UPDATE #2

**notifications/index.html.erb**

```
    <% if !@notifications.blank? %>
        <%= render partial: "notifications/notification", collection: @notifications %> 
    <% else %>
        <p>No notifications... yet</p>
    <% end %>
```

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_create :create_notification
  has_many :notifications
  has_many :comment_likes   
  has_many :likers, through: :comment_likes, class_name: 'User', source: :liker
    belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
    belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :activity

private

  def create_notification
    @activity = Activity.find_by(self.activity)
    @user = User.find_by(@activity.user_id).id
      Notification.create(
       activity_id: self.activity,
       user_id: @user,
       comment_id: self,
       read: false
      )
  end
end
```

**_create_notifications.rb**

```
class CreateNotifications < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :notifications do |t|
      t.references :activity, index: true
      t.references :comment, index: true
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.boolean :read

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :notifications, :activities
    add_foreign_key :notifications, :comments
    add_foreign_key :notifications, :users
  end
end
```

Comment: First things first, so without looking into your second problem... Do you still have the error when you change your URL to `activity_path(notification.activity)`?

Answer (score 0):

To determine on which page the `activity` is located, you could do the following:

```
activity = Activity.find(notification.activity_id)
index    = Activity.order(created_at: :desc).index(activity)
```

The above will determine the `index` of the `activity` within all of the activities.

So, let's say you've got 85 activities. You've got 20 activities per page, so in this case you would have 5 pages, right? Alright, let's assume the above `index` returns 42. To calculate the page number you would have to do this (assuming that you've got a variable called `per_page` which is 20):

```
page_number = (index / per_page.to_f).ceil
```

You've got `index` 42. Which you'll have to divide by the number of activities per page (it **needs** to be a float!), so that would be `20.0`. That results in `2.1`. `ceil` that and you've got your page number, which would be 3.

So, to create the correct paginated path, you can now do this:

```
activities_path(page: page_number)
```

**Update**

Now that we know that the `activity_id` isn't correctly set on the `notification` we can fix that (also note that the `comment_id` isn't set either). Change the last part of your `Comment` model to this:

```
...

belongs_to :activity

validates :activity_id, presence: true
validates :user_id, presence: true

private

def create_notification
  Notification.create(activity_id: self.activity_id, user_id: self.user_id, comment_id: self.id, read: false)
end
```

I've added two validations here to make sure the `activity_id` and `user_id` are set. Now as I said before the `comment_id` isn't set either. That's because the `id` is only assigned on `save`, on `create` you are just setting it up to be saved. So, change the `after_create :create_notification` to `after_save :create_notification` to be able to set the `comment_id` as well.

That should set the `activity_id` and `comment_id`. Now for the next part. Getting the correct page number which should be added to the link in your `_notification.html.erb` partial.

Add these methods to your `Activity` class:

```
def page_number
  (index / per_page.to_f).ceil
end

private

def index
  Activity.order(created_at: :desc).index self
end
```

Now change the path in your `notifications/_notification.html.erb` partial to:

```
activities_path(page: notification.activity.page_number)
```

Note: If you get an error about the `per_page` in the `page_number` method you probably haven't set the value `per_page` in the model itself (like [this](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate#basic-will_paginate-use); Basically add `self.per_page = 20` to your model right below `class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base`)

If you decide to do it like this, you can remove the `, :per_page => 20` part in your `ActivitiesController`. If not, simply replace `per_page.to_f` with `20.to_f` or `20.0`.

Also, remove the 3 lines from your `NotificationsController` which you've commented out previously to find out whether the `activity_id` was set or not. You don't need them anymore, since we've placed them in the `Activity` class.

Comment: Hey if you have 10 minutes (max) I'd love to run by you a few of the minor problems I ran into with some of your code. Would you be willing to stack chat, skype, facetime, gotomeeting or whatever works for you?

Comment: What do you want to know? Do you wonder where this code belongs? You mentioned that you've got a `notifications/_notifications.html.erb` partial. So, I'm guessing you've got a `NotificationsController` with a `show` action. This code belongs in there. Besides that you had an error with the `activity_path`. I don't think you should be linking to the `show` view at all, the `your activity` link should simply link to `activities_path(page: page_number)` where `page_number` is calculated in the `NotificationsController#show` action.

Comment: Hey okay so there is no `show` action in the `NotificationsController`, but there is an `index` action. I updated question with my attempt there. With the error I don't know. maybe it's with the config. Updated there as well. And then I ran into errors with `page_number`. I then tried `:page_number` instead but that gave me an error too. Further explanation in question :)

Comment: Ok, first of all. How do you get `notification` in your `notifications/_notifications.html.erb` partial? Do you have a `notifications/index.html.erb` where you are including the `_notifications.html.erb` partial? If so, what does it look like? Also, how are these `notifications` created? Do you have a `new` and `create` action in your `NotificationsController`? I've updated my answer with a small fix (just part of it), which might work.

Comment: Yes to first two questions. Updated question. I also followed this tutorial changing his "post" for my "activity" http://evanamccullough.com/2014/11/ruby-on-rails-simple-notifications-system-tutorial/, but no need to click on it because I also updated the question with where I create these notifications. Answer to final question, no. I had shown full notifications controller. I tried your fix but that hadn't worked for me either, giving me the same error message as before: `Couldn't find Activity with 'id'=`

Comment: Ok, I think I know how to fix your problem. First I want to make sure that your `notifications` actually have an `activity_id`. If you don't know how to find this out, try this: comment out the 3 lines you've added to the `NotificationsController`. Right above it add this: `puts "notification: #{notification.inspect}"`. Search for `notification: ` in your Rails log and make sure `activity_id` is set in all of the notifications.

Comment: Nice technique. Makes no sense to me how it can still be nil @newmediafreak  `notification: #<Notification id: 3, activity_id: nil, comment_id: nil, user_id: 1, read: true, created_at: "2015-05-08 03:17:55", updated_at: "2015-05-08 03:18:11">`

Comment: Maybe I did the routes wrong? or I have to add some sort of line to build that relationship when I create a notification in comment.rb?

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com Checkout the **Update** part of my answer. I think that should do it. If not, let me know. Also, remove any previous 'incorrect' notifications (those without an `activity_id`) and create a new one (with the updated code) or update them through your console with `bundle exec rails console` to add a valid `activity_id`.

Comment: Looked very promising and then when I tested it out by creating a new comment on an activity I got : `NoMethodError in CommentsController#create undefined method 'activity_id' for #<Comment:0x007f94e4cd1f88>` for line: `if @comment.save`. If I remove `validates :activity_id, presence: true` that gets rid of that error but then we are faced with a new one... the dreaded: `NoMethodError in CommentsController#create undefined method 'activity_id' for #<Comment:0x007f94de051fe8>` for line: `activity_id: self.activity_id, ` Do we need to add `t.integer  "activity_id"` to the comments table?

Comment: Even though comments are polymorphic? and activities has `has_many :comments, as: :commentable` or do I need to something else to the activities table in the schema? I'll keep playing with it for now and thanks for your awesome update!

Comment: What happens when you change `validates :activity_id` to `validates :activity` (and the same for `user_id`)?

Comment: I had tried that but that gave us `NameError in Comments#create undefined local variable or method 'new_comment' for... <%= form_for new_comment, url: send(create_url, new_comment.commentable) do |f| %>` in comments/_form. This line came from Joe's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29806363/how-to-submit-polymorphic-comments-on-feed-error.

Comment: I removed `.id`  here in the activities/index, which refers to `:new_comment`: `<%= render "comments/form", new_comment: Comment.new(commentable_id: activity.id, commentable_type: activity.class.model_name), create_url: :activity_comments_path %>` but the error remained. If you'd like NewMediaFreak I can ask a new SO question to solve this specific problem because you've already gone above and beyond with your awesome updates and answer :)

Comment: Yeah, that would be better. This is a totally different issue. I'm pretty sure the paginated URL will work once your associations are sorted out.