# undefined local variable or method `new_comment`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> NameError in Comments#create
>
> Showing /**comments/_form.html.erb**
>   where line #1 raised:
>
> undefined local variable or method `new_comment` for #<#:0x007fb9760eb640>

```
<%= form_for new_comment, url: send(create_url, new_comment.commentable) do |f| %>
```

`new_comment` is being called by:

**activities/index.html.erb**

`<%= render "comments/form", new_comment: Comment.new(commentable_id: activity.id, commentable_type: activity.class.model_name), create_url: :activity_comments_path %>`

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :create_notification #ERROR OCCURRED WHEN I INTRODUCED THIS LINE AND
  validates :activity, presence: true #THIS LINE
  validates :user, presence: true
  has_many :notifications
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :activity

private

  def create_notification
    Notification.create(
      activity_id: self.activity_id, 
      user_id: self.user_id, 
      comment_id: self.id, 
      read: false
      )
  end
end
```

**notification.rb**

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :activity
  belongs_to :comment
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**activity.rb**

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.per_page = 20
  has_many :notifications
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  belongs_to :trackable, polymorphic: true

  def conceal
    trackable.conceal
  end

  def page_number
    (index / per_page.to_f).ceil
  end

private

  def index
    Activity.order(created_at: :desc).index self
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :activities do
  resources :comments
  resources :notifications
  member do
    post :like
    post :notifications
  end
end
```

Any ideas on what maybe the cause? This error is coming off of the awesome answer here: [How to make a path to a paginated url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30134662/how-to-make-a-path-to-a-paginated-url)

**Thank you!**

### UPDATE

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :load_commentable
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :like]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

    def index
        @comments = @commentable.comments
    end

    def new
        @comment = @commentable.comments.new
    end

    def create
        @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
        if @comment.save
            redirect_to @commentable, notice: "comment created."
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    def edit
        @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
        if @comment.update_attributes(comment_params)
            redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Comment was updated."
        else
            render :edit
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
        @comment.destroy
        redirect_to @commentable, notice: "comment destroyed."
    end

  def like
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment_like = current_user.comment_likes.build(comment: @comment)
    if @comment_like.save
            @comment.increment!(:likes)
        flash[:success] = 'Thanks for liking!'
    else
        flash[:error] = 'Two many likes'
      end  
        redirect_to(:back)
  end

private

  def set_comment
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end

    def load_commentable
        resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2]
        @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
    end

    def comment_params
        params[:comment][:user_id] = current_user.id
        params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :commentable, :user_id, :like)
    end
end
```

**notifications_controller**

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
    def index
    @notifications = current_user.notifications
    @notifications.each do |notification|
        notification.update_attribute(:read, true)
    end
    end


    def destroy
      @notification = Notification.find(params[:id])
      @notification.destroy
      redirect_to :back
    end
end
```

**activities_controller**

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @activities = Activity.order("created_at desc").paginate(:page => params[:page])
    end

    def show
          redirect_to(:back)
    end

  def like
    @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
    @activity_like = current_user.activity_likes.build(activity: @activity)
    if @activity_like.save
      @activity.increment!(:likes)
      flash[:success] = 'Thanks for liking!'
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Two many likes'
    end  
      redirect_to(:back)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `<%= form_for comment do |f| %>` not new comment since comment is the element in your database

Comment: Thanks Zippo! That gives me `NameError in Activities#index defined local variable or method 'comment' for` that line. It worked prior to implementing those two lines I mentioned in the comments.rb comments. I got `new_comment` from Joe's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29806363/how-to-submit-polymorphic-comments-on-feed-error

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com please post your controller code also

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com Try this: `<%= form_for @comment, url: send(create_url, @comment.commentable) do |f| %>`

Comment: Nope @anusha that gave: `NoMethodError in Activities#index
Showing /comments/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:
undefined method 'commentable' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com what about this `<%= form_for @comment, url: send(create_url) do |f| %>`

Comment: That gives @anusha: `ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Activities#index
Showing /comments/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:
No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"comments"} missing required keys: [:activity_id]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77769/discussion-between-anusha-and-anthonygalli-com).

Comment: Hi @anusha I keep checking your profile to see when you are on, but I can never seem to catch you. When would work for you to continue our conversation? Thanks again :)

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com Can we continue the discussion

Comment: Hey @anusha can you pick a time or two? I'll make myself flexible to whatever you need. My time zone is New York.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com I am available now till 4 to 5 hours. If it is possible for you then we will discuss

Comment: @anusha can you chat now? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77769/discussion-between-anusha-and-anthonygalli-com